# paginate error while using will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I am trying to display all my users and want to paginate them 
I added these two gems :

```
gem 'paginate', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.10'
```

The following line gives me an error :

```
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I have tried `@users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])`
and `@users = User.paginate :all, :page => params[:page]`

The error is :
`You tried to define a scope named "paginate" on the model "ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.`

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaking gems, will_paginate is [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) and should be added with

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

while you're actually adding [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/paginate) gem with your above statement .